# Issue with hiding div using cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

Im trying to create a div that only pops up once a month. After you click it away I want a cookie to make sure it doesn't appear again.

The block goes away, but as soon as I refresh the page the div is back again so the cookie doesn't seem to be working.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code I'm using:

HTML:

```
<div id="lightboxz" class="lightbox">
  <table class="lightbox_table">
    <tr>
      <td class="lightbox_table_cell" align="center">
        <div id="lightbox_content">
          <div id="closedat" onclick="Mailsign()"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i> </div> 

          {loadmodule mod_mailchimpsignup}

        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Mailsign(){

    days=30;
    myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));

    document.cookie = 'Mailsign=Accepted; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
    document.getElementById('lightboxz').style.display='none';
}

function CheckCookies(){   
    if ($.cookie("Mailsign") === "Accepted")
    {
        $("#lightboxz").hide();
    } 
}
```

**Update**:
The cookie is getting installed, so the issue is clearly with the `CheckCookies` function. Could this be a jQuery conflict with other jQuery code on the site?

Comment: Are you including jQuery in your page somewhere? Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Yes Im currently thinking so, since the cookie does get installed on my browser
Im trying to figure out how to solve that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things here - you're likely going to want to have the div hidden by default so you don't have a brief period where it shows and then disappears.

```
<div id="lightboxz" class="lightbox"></div>
.lightbox { display: none; }
```

You also need to actually call the CheckCookies(), but make sure you do it when the document is ready! i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   CheckCookies();
});
```

I will say that it seems as though `localStorage` would work just as well in this scenario and avoid the need for cookies.

```
function Mailsign(){
   days=30;
   myDate = new Date();
   myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
   localStorage.setItem('popup', myDate);
}

function CheckCookies(){   
    var today = new Date();
    var showDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem('popup'));
    if (!localStorage.getItem('popup') || today > showDate)
    {
        $("#lightboxz").show();
    } 
}
```

http://codepen.io/harangue/pen/dMJRMo

Comment: I want the div to always be visible until someone clicked the close button

Using the above stated code results into the div never showing at all
Ive never used Localstorage so I might be doing it wrong though

Comment: Nope, it works @user2620358. See my example I added.

Comment: I clearly did something wrong before, because when I use your example (After adding jquery no conflict) works perfectly! Thank you very much for this option!
One small question, if I want to see it again (For testing purposes) how can I do that?

Comment: @user2620358 You can just `localStorage.clear()` or if you have other things stored `localStorage.removeItem('popup')`.